# Why neutrino mass hierarchy scenario do not include the case $m_2<m_1<m_3$ and the case $m_3<m_2<m_1$?

Tags: mass, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

The neutrino mass hierarchies are made of two hypotheses/scenarios:

- the normal hierarchy: $m1<m2<m3$
- the inverted hierarchy: $m3<m1<m2$

Why neutrino mass hierarchy scenario do not include also the cases:

- $m2<m1<m3$?
- $m3<m2<m1$?

I have seen the post: 
[Neutrino mass hierarchy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/297449/)

but two people are in contradiction and there was no conclusion on who is right.
@SRS is saying in this thread that it is a convention to have $m_1<m_2$. Is he right? wrong? Is there a proof of the convention from a statement in a document?

Comment: Convention in every neutrino paper is to take $m_1<m_2$, proof is more or less the PDG paper on neutrino physics

Comment: Thank you @Triatticus. I put the link of pdg for those people that follow the discussion : http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2019-rev-neutrino-mixing.pdf page 26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $m_1$ is less than $m_2$ from solar neutrino measurements of the MSW effect. Here's a quote from a paper that addresses this

> Solar neutrinos allow to fix the sign of $\Delta m^2_{21}$for the standard value of $V_e$. The sign determines the resonance channel (neutrino or antineutrino) and the mixing in matter. The facts that due to smallness of the 1-3 mixing the problem is reduced approximately to the $2\nu$-problem and that suppression of signal averaged over the oscillations at high energies  is  stronger  than  1/2,  selects $\Delta m^{2}_{21} > 0 $.

-- [Solar neutrinos and neutrino physics, Maltoni & Smirnov.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05287.pdf)

Put simply we measure the survival probability of solar neutrinos to be (more or less) like this...
[image: survival probability]
[Image from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MSW_%2B_4_branches.svg).

Where the probability at low energies is ~60% and at high energies is about 30%.
If $\Delta m^{2}_{21}$ were negative you would see at high energies the survival probability dip to some value of ~50% at ~1MeV then go back up to ~60% at higher energies. (Caveat, most of the numbers above are made up, take them with a grain of salt).

Comment: Is m1 < m3 < m2 ruled out?

Comment: Yes, that possibility is ruled out by the fact that $\Delta m^{2}_{21}$ is ~$10^{-5}$ eV$^2$ and $\Delta m^{2}_{31}$ is around $10^{-3}$ eV$^2$. I.e the mass difference between the $m_{1}$ state and the $m_{3}$ state is very large compared to the difference between the $m_{1}$ state and the $m_{2}$ state. So the only remaining possibilities are $m_{1} < m_{2} < m_{3}$ or $m_{3} < m_{1} < m_{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to find a concrete answer to this question and just came across this quote from https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04946;

> Note that the observation of matter effects in the Sun constrains the product $\Delta m_{21}^2 \cos 2θ_{12}$ to be positive. Therefore, depending on the convention chosen to describe solar neutrino oscillations, matter effects either fix the sign of the solar mass splitting $\Delta m_{21}^2$ or the octant of the solar angle $θ_{12}$, with $\Delta m_{21}^2$ positive by definition.

So the answer appears to be both. Though I have seen more documents fixing the octant of the angle than the sign of the splitting.