# Lepton Universality

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, leptons

Does universality of lepton also mean that two lepton families have the same renormalized coupling if they interact with a particular particle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton#Universality): “The coupling of leptons to all types of **gauge boson** are flavour-independent: The interaction between leptons and a gauge boson measures the same for each lepton.” [Note: Recent experiments are raising questions about this.]

Lepton universality does not apply to their Higgs couplings; if it did, they would have the same mass.

As ACuriousMind put it so well [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229473/help-me-understand-lepton-universality), “Lepton universality means all leptons behave the same, except when they don't.”

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So if i have a model containing electron, muon and a mediating particle (say, photon), the renormalized coupling for interaction between electrons and the mediator, and the renormalized coupling for interaction between muons and the mediator should be the same, if there is a lepton universality. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes. In the case you mention, involving a photon, the coupling is simply the electric charge. Universality of lepton-photon coupling means nothing more than that muons and tauons have the same charge as electrons. Perhaps it is less “obvious” or well-known that they couple in the same way to $W$ and $Z$ bosons.

Comment: Thank you so much again, it was really helpful.